# Why am I Encountering 403 Error On Windows Service Container?

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, windows-services

I'm new to docker and am working on trying to containerize one of my org's solutions. It's a windows service that is used to build data packages that are distributed to clients. It has a small web front end that is used to interact with it and kick off package builds. After building the image and running the container, I have all of the binaries from the Visual Studio solution copied over to a directory under C:/inetpub/wwwroot on the container, and have a port mapping from 1337 on my host machine to 80 on the container.

However, when I try to browse to localhost:1337 to access the web front end for the service running on the container I get a 403 error like the linked image. Would anyone happen to know what might be causing this? Dockerfile is pasted below as well for reference, thanks in advance for any help.

403 Error Page

[image: 1]

```
# escape=\

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

COPY ./bin /inetpub/wwwroot/

RUN icacls 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot' /grant 'Everyone:(OI)(CI)F'

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/"
RUN New-Service -Name "\"CDR"\"  -StartupType "\"Automatic"\"  -BinaryPathName "\"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\CDR_Service.exe"\";

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell"]
CMD Start-Service \""CDR Service\""; \
    Get-EventLog -LogName System -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) | Format-List ;\
    $idx = (get-eventlog -LogName System -Newest 1).Index; \
    while ($true) \
    {; \
    start-sleep -Seconds 1; \
    $idx2  = (Get-EventLog -LogName System -newest 1).index; \
    get-eventlog -logname system -newest ($idx2 - $idx) |  sort index | Format-List; \
    $idx = $idx2; \
    }
```

Created Dockerfile for windows service based on template I found on stackoverflow. Built an image using it after making the necessary changes for my specific app. Ran container from generated image expecting to be able to browse to the dashboard of the app, but am encountering a 403 forbidden error whenever browsing to it.